# Service to process/filter inbound email

Tags: email, smtp

[Mandrill](http://mandrillapp.com) has inbound email processing, in which you can setup a catch-all address for which incoming e-mail will be posted to a specified URL.

For example, e-mails to `*@sub.domain.com` could get posted to `http://mydomain.com/process`.

Is there a service that will work this way but that allows to "re-route" the e-mails? Say if a post to the URL above returns a specific code, say 403, the e-mail will be swallowed, but when a 200 code is returned, the e-mail gets sent to a specific address, without modification, just as if it was originally sent to that address.

I guess I could code a script that would just re-send the e-mail, but I don't want to run into deliverability issues.

I'm not sure I'm explaining this clearly, so here's a specific example:

1. E-mail to `newsletters@sub.domain.com` is received by a Mandrill-like service (the receiver)
2. That service posts the e-mail to `http://mydomain.com/process` (let's call this the processor)
3. The processor either:

   1. Returns a 403, in which case nothing else happens
   2. Returns a 200, and a destination address, and then the receiver delivers that e-mail to the new destination

**EDIT:** I realize I could just use Mandrill to re-send the e-mail, but wouldn't I run into problems given I won't be the original sender? For example, if I receive an e-mail from `support@microsoft.com` and then I re-send that e-mail to another address, could I be flagged as a spammer or have other issues with deliverability? So this might not be possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is indeed impossible to do what I want, otherwise anybody could spam the world with no problems, however, Mandrill just added this feature, which might come in handy:

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23374656-Can-I-send-emails-on-behalf-of-my-clients-

This is just an experiment, but I'm going to try and resend mails to my own server instead of forwarding to the original receiver, so then an e-mail client can pull the messages from there.